# Infinte scroll function is not fetching the data in php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i am trying to make infinite scroll in php where i  have index page in which the data is fetched and showed the results and in getrecord page the mysql code is there.

now i am sending data  '**anotherID**' from  *index* page to *getrecord* page but *getrecord* page is not fetching the data of **anotherID** it shows no result found . please help me and in advance thanks. here is my code

Index page

```html
   


 <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
       

        <div class="col-lg-12" id="results"></div>
        <div id="loader_image"><img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24"> Loading...please wait</div>
        <div class="margin10"></div>
        <div id="loader_message"></div>

      </div>


   
   

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var busy = false;
      var limit = 15;
      var offset = 0;
   var anotherID = 0;

      function displayRecords(lim, off, anotherID) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          url: "getrecords.php",
          data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off + "&anotherID=" + anotherID,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
          },
          success: function(html) {
            $("#results").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
              $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
            } else {
              $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Loading please wait...</button>').show();
            }
            window.busy = false;


          }
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        // start to load the first set of data
        if (busy == false) {
          busy = true;
          // start to load the first set of data
          displayRecords(limit, offset);
        }


        $(window).scroll(function() {
          // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
          if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {
            busy = true;
            offset = limit + offset;

            // this is optional just to delay the loading of data
            setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);

            // you can remove the above code and can use directly this function
            // displayRecords(limit, offset);

          }
        });

      });

    </script>


    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

getrecords page

```html
<?php

require_once("config.php");

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$anotherID = $_GET['anotherID'];

$sql = "SELECT countries_name,cat FROM countries WHERE  category = '$anotherID'  ORDER BY countries_name ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<h3>' . $res['countries_name'] . '</h3>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You never supply anotherID as an argument to your function. It’s always 0 as defined in the variable declaration

Comment: @LegenJerry i have different category in database so i want to view results of same category where category is 0 or pc so have given o in anotherid

Comment: Your code is suseptable to SQL Injection. Use prepared statements and bind the variables to your statement..Have you tried calling your php from the browser address bar with the parameters to see what you get?